# What gets executed first in a nested function?

Tags: xcode, swift, closures

When I create a constant to put my closure to work:

> ```
> let incrementByTen = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)
> ```

Does it skip **incrementer()** until it's called in the return statement, that way the return statement can run the incrementer() function in the end and receive its value?

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0
    func incrementer() -> Int {
        runningTotal += amount
        return runningTotal
    }
    return incrementer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to a function are evaluated when the function is called.  In this case that means that when `makeIncrementer` is called, it's argument (10 in this case) will be evaluated before `makeIncrementer` is actually called.

Likewise, when `makeIncrementer` is invoked, it's code will be executed in sequence, initializing `runningTotal` and then initializing `incrementer`  (note that at this point `amount` has been evaluated already, so in the returned incremented, it is ALWAYS 10.

Subsequently, when you invoke `incrementByTen()` there are no arguments to pass and nothing to be evaluated before the call, as part of executing the closure, runningTotal will be incremented by amount, in this case, always 10.

Comment: I've read that this function captures a reference to runningTotal and amount. What's hard to grasp is how it keeps increasing when I repeatedly call incrementByTen().

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you have extended your question with:

> I've read that this function captures a reference to runningTotal and amount. What's hard to grasp is how it keeps increasing when I repeatedly call incrementByTen().

The function `incrementer` captures the *value* of `amount` and the *variable* `runningTotal`. Capturing a value just involves copying the value into the *function value* (aka *closure*).

Capturing the *variable* is more involved: as a local variable `runningTotal`'s lifetime would usually only extend at most to the end of the function invocation it is created by - so a call to `makeIncrementer` would create a new local `runningTotal` and when that call returned the variable would be destroyed. **However** as `runningTotal` is captured as a variable by `incrementer` then its lifetime is automatically extended as long as it is required by `incrementer`, which is as long as `incrementer` itself is required. As `incrementer` is the value returned by `makeIncrementer` the lifetime of `runningTotal` extends past the lifetime of the call to `makeIncrementer`.

Later each time the function returned by a *single* call to `makeIncrementer` is invoked as it has captured the variable `runningTotal` from that call it is incremented by 10 and its current value returned.

If you call `makeIncrementer` twice and store both results, then each result references a *distinct* function and each of those functions references a *distinct* variable - so you have two distinct incrementing counters.

HTH